# Android how to set Daily Alarm at a specific time?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to assume every day exactly at 10am will play music, i used Brocast to do that but time is not correct and played music 10 hours earlier

```
<receiver android:name=".component.main.profile.AlarmReceiverBedTime"/>

Declare BroadcastReceiver
class AlarmReceiverBedTime : BroadcastReceiver(){
    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        Log.d("TEST_BRO","onReceive")
        val rightNow = Calendar.getInstance()
        val currentHourIn24Format: Int =rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val currentMinuteIn24Format:Int=rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
        Log.d("TEST_HOUR_MINUTE", "$currentHourIn24Format $currentMinuteIn24Format")
    }
}

In Activity 
 private fun addBroadcastBedTime() {
        val myIntent = Intent(this@TimeSleepActivity, AlarmReceiverBedTime::class.java)
        val alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            this@TimeSleepActivity,
            0,
            myIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar[Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY] = 10
        calendar[Calendar.MINUTE] = 0
        calendar[Calendar.SECOND] = 0
        alarmManager.setRepeating(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.timeInMillis,
            (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toLong(),
            pendingIntent
        )
    }
```

But code in function onReceive() is called early before 10 o'clock not exactly at 10 o'clock. Sorry my english very bad